# Greater than or equal to a date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that has a field called date1.

When I look at the table in Access GUI datasheet view, I can see the dates are "correct in that date1 runs from October 1st 2013 to today, June 19th 2014. When I look at table1 in design view I can see that date1 is formatted as m/d/yyyy.

So when I ran this query I expected to see results only for April 1st 2014 till today. But instead I see results going back to 2013.

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable
WHERE ((([someTable].medium1)='Direct'))
OR ((([someTable].medium1)='Paid Search') 
AND (([someTable].date1)>=#4/1/2014#));
```

I tried removing the # too. I only added those after doing some Google searching.

Can anyone spot why my query is returning results where date1 is less than April 1st 2014?

Comment: Your date needs to be encapsulated in a string I think. `'#4/1/2014#'`

Comment: What kind of field is `Date1`? Is it actually a `Date/Time` field?

Comment: I think your OR is throwing off results.  is the date inclusive of the other criteria? (meaning all values should be after that date? `([someTable].medium1='Direct' OR [someTable].medium1)='Paid Search') 
AND ([someTable].date1)>=#4/1/2014#);` Always loved Access and their () use

Comment: @xQbert is hinting at a good point. Let's look at the query results piece by piece and make sure you're seeing the correct results. Run it with 1 `WHERE` clause at a time, and see what if gives you.

Comment: The name of the field doesn't really matter; what's important is the **datatype** of the database column. If that's a VARCHAR column, then the inequality predicate (as in you query) is going to be a _string_ comparison, the two string values compared character by character. And `'5/1/2013'` (e.g.) would in fact be "greater than" `'4/1/2014'`.  (And rows with `medium1='Direct'` will be returned without regard to the `date1` column (because of the boolean `OR` combining the predicates.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your OR is throwing off results.

Is the date inclusive of the other criteria? (meaning all values should be after that date? if so the where clause is off.

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable
WHERE ([someTable].medium1 = 'Direct' OR [someTable].medium1 = 'Paid Search')
AND   ([someTable].date1)>=#4/1/2014#);
```

Or...

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable
WHERE [someTable].medium1 in ('Direct', 'Paid Search')  
 AND  [someTable].date1 >= #4/1/2014#;
```

or...

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable
WHERE ([someTable].medium1='Direct' OR [someTable].medium1='Paid Search')
AND   [someTable].date1>=#4/1/2014#;
```

Comment: thanks @xQbert that was it. Still getting to grips with SQL but looks like I was selecting condition1,2 OR date greater than April first, as opposed to AND. Bracketing was the issue. Thanks, accepting shortly!

Answer (score 2):

The data in the view depends of the field format. When the query is launched, the data is returned "as-is. You have to ensure the date format by using the `format` function.

Use this query instead:

```
select *
from someTable
where someTable.date1 between format("04/01/2014","mm/dd/yyyy") and now()
and someTable.medium1 in ('Direct','Paid Search')
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm familiar with casting dates as a particular format but in this instance because I'm on Access I was pretty sure my date formats where correct as I loaded them in like that.

Comment: Dates are the devil of every programmer, be sure of that! ;)